# Accidentally trashed my poke balls and incense, how do I recover discarded items?

Tags: pokemon-go

I accidentally trashed my poke balls and incense in the items. How can I recover the most important part of the game. I can't get any poke balls now!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to recover any discarded items.  You must get new items by visiting PokeStops, leveling up, or purchasing them from the shop.